# how to factorize x^(x+1) without using math.pow

Tags: c#, algorithm

I tried this:

```
static int myPow(int x)
        {
            int power = x + 1;
            int num = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < power; i++)
            {
                num = x * i;
                x = x + num;
            }
            return num;
        }
```

how can I factorize the int `x` by `x+1` without using `Math.Pow`?

Comment: It would help if you'd show us your use of Math.Pow so we can substitute it!

Comment: Run what you have in the debugger, look at the variable values, and see if you can figure out where you went wrong (hint: x should never change)

Comment: Also this will overflow for any x larger than 8.

Comment: @dan this is likely an educational exercise.

Comment: What does "factorize" mean here? Do you mean that you want to compute the value x^(x+1)? (If so, note that the maximum integer is one less than 2^32 = 8^8, so, as @D Stanley points out, you can't fit the answer in an `int` unless x < 8.)

Comment: @TedHopp Not to detract from your point, but 2^32 = 16^8.  8^9 will fit in an `int` but 9^10 will not.

Comment: @D Stanley - Oops. Thanks for catching that. :)

Comment: One thing that might help realize one of your mistakes is to understand that x ^ (x+1) is equivalent to just multiplication. Example... 5 ^ (5 + 1) = 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5... there is no addition in that.

Comment: Sometimes you can solve a specific problem more easily by solving a general problem. Can you write a method `static int IntPow(int x, int y)` that computes x to the y?  If you can write that method, then your method is just `MyPow(int x) => IntPow(x, x+1);`  I think you will find it easier to write the more general method.  Hint:  Start by making sure that your method is correct for y = 0.  Next: what is the definition of x to the y for y >= 1? Can you translate that definition into code?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to multiply X by X in a loop by X+1 times.

Follow the steps:

- find the power (x + 1)
- start the variable result with the x value (result = x)
- loop i from 1 to power and for each loop multiply result by x, witch means x * x * x * x power times.

  ```
  static int myPow(int x) {
      int power = x + 1;
      int result = x;
      for (int i = 1; i < power; i++)
      {
          result *= x;
      }
      return result;
  }
  ```

Take a look on the implementation it did on [rextester](http://rextester.com/OAXZ58285)

Comment: I think you should switch to `long` to avoid overflows.

Answer (score 0):

FYI factorization in math is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization). Just for fun, the result can be calculated with [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring):

```
static int myPow(int x, int y)
{            
    if (y < 0) { throw new ArgumentException("y has to be nonnegative"); }
    int result = 1;
    while (y > 0)
    {
        if ((y & 1) == 1)
        {
            result *= x;
        }
        x = x * x;
        y >>= 1;
    }            
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a technique called **exponentiation by squaring**, which is quite beautiful and is also faster, it takes **O(lg k)** time, where **k** is exponent:

```
static int square(int n){
    return n * n;
}
static int pow(int n, int k){
    if(k == 1) return n;
    if(k % 2 == 1) return n * pow(n, k-1);
    return square(pow(n, k/2));
}
```

then, if you want to get x^(x+1), you just need yo call `pow(x, x+1)`.

small, fast and simple as that :)

Comment: In your pow function: if k == 0, return 1 (this is probably fine [even if n = 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#IEEE_floating_point_standard)).  If k < 0, either throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or implement roots.

Comment: the answer was to make x^(x+1), so I thought it was for naturals

Comment: Then maybe name it `powForNaturalExponents` so that future users of the class containing this static function don't try to call it on unsupported arguments?